# Criar branch a partir de outro branch

Tags: git

Não sei se o título deixa claro o que quero fazer mas é o seguinte, tenho a develop(raiz) e a develop2.0(reformulação do sistema). Gostaria de saber como criar uma branch que ao ser finalizada, faça o merge com a develop2.0 em vez de fazer com a develop.

Comment: `git checkout -b meunovobranch develop2.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer é trabalhar com feature branch - isso é um conceito de fluxo de trabalho em Git.

Basicamente, a partir da branch "raiz" de seu desenvolvimento, neste caso a `develop2.0`, você cria branches para cada funcionalidade que for desenvolver, e ao finalizar faz um merge da feature branch na `develop2.0`.

O fluxo seria o seguinte:

1. certifique-se que está na branch `develop2.0`

```bsh
git status
```

1.1. caso não esteja, vá para branch `develop2.0`

```bsh
git checkout develop2.0
```

2. a partir da branch `develop2.0` inicie a feature branch para trabalhar na funcionalidade, vamos chamar de v2.0-f1 por exemplo:

```bsh
git checkout -b v2.0-f1
```

3. trabalhe na recém criada branch `v2.0-f1` até finalizar as alterações e estar pronto de fazer o merge em `develop2.0`

3.1 ao finalizar e estar pronto de mesclar as novas alterações, volte para branch `develop2.0`

```bsh
git checkout develop2.0
```

3.2 estando na branch `develop2.0` mescle as alterações de `v2.0-f1`

```bsh
git merge v2.0-f1
```

4. Reincie o fluxo para a próxima feature

Espero que este fluxo lhe auxilie, utilizo ele com equipe de 2 ou mais desenvolvedores e funciona bem.

Comment: isso mesmo, cara muito obrigado funcionou muito bem, e inclusive dessa forma eu posso até remover a branch após o merge caso eu não precise mais usá-la, vlw ajudou muito

Comment: isso mesmo, fez o merge remove a feature-branch.

Aproveito e peço que marque a resposta como aceita, assim outros podem identificar como uma solução real para o problema